# MySQL application runs slow after general usage

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I am currently using MySQL. I have noticed several times my front application runs slow after some usage. when i checked server status in MySQL workbench. I have noticed that innodb buffer usage was going to 100% . so I increased parameter innodb_buffer_pool_size to 1G in my.ini file of xampp. but innodb is not flushing the buffer and application runs slow after some time. is there any other parameters to change as-well?

Comment: If you're just asking how to flush the buffer, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10542853/2359271

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider using a size for innodb_buffer_pool_size of 70%-80% of available ram. Depending on how big your dataset is, you should increase the size.