# MySQL Storage Engine

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat7

I have Tomcat 7  & MySQL 5.5 version install in a system.
Since last month i am facing problem with **Got Error 12 from storage engine**.
Bcz of these tomcat server not working properly & it crashes. When i restart the Machine Tomcat Server works correctly. Then again after 8-10 days it gives me same issue. 
So i search on these but i couldn't able to get correct solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQfxF.png)

What will be the correct way to resolve MySQL Storage Engine Problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the link about [how to clear/flush mysql innodb buffer pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542853/how-to-clear-flush-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool) yet? Or the one about [Clear MySQL query cache without restarting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231678/clear-mysql-query-cache-without-restarting-server).

Comment: Interesting, you want to clear something that doesn't need clearing. Do you know what that is and why do you want to clear it? What do you get by clearing that?

Comment: @Mjh , bcz i'm facing problem in Storage engine. To be honest i don't have idea about it. So what is meaning of buffer cache?

Comment: @Amol1523 - may I suggest you ask a question about your real problem, not about something you think could be related to it? You're going to solve your issue much quicker. If you have a storage engine problem, why not ask how to fix that?

Comment: @Mjh- i got a solution in that they suggest me to increased MySQL buffer cache size.So i fixed by increasing key_cache_block_size & key_buffer_size. Is it correct solution? If not what will be the correct way to solve storage engine problem?

Comment: I've no idea what the solution is or if it is a solution if I don't know the problem. I can't help you. The correct way to solve the problem is to first tell everyone what the problem **is**. You concluded somehow there's a storage engine problem. Include that in your question, don't let people pluck bits of information from you.. you're a grown man, you should be able to communicate about problems like these.